# Core plot: axis alternatingBandFills with majorTickLocations inproper display

Tags: ios, colors, core-plot

I am setting the majorTickLocations property of the yAxis with some predefined ranges values. I am also setting the alternatingBandFills property of the yAxis to colour-code those ranges. The code I am using looks as follows:

```
     NSSet *majorTickLocations = [NSSet setWithObjects:
                                 [NSDecimalNumber numberWithDouble:lowerRedRangeFrom],
                                 [NSDecimalNumber numberWithDouble:lowerOrangeRangeFrom],
                                 [NSDecimalNumber numberWithDouble:greenRangeFrom],
                                 [NSDecimalNumber numberWithDouble:upperOrangeRangeFrom],
                                 [NSDecimalNumber numberWithDouble:upperRedRangeFrom],
                                 [NSDecimalNumber numberWithDouble:upperRedRangeTo],
                                 nil];
    yAxis.majorTickLocations = majorTickLocations;

    yAxis.alternatingBandFills = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                      [CPTColor redColor],
                                      [CPTColor orangeColor],
                                      [CPTColor greenColor],
                                      [CPTColor orangeColor],
                                      [CPTColor redColor], nil];
```

Everything is fine besides one particular problem:

Some of the ranges of the data I am using have lowerRedRangeFrom = lowerOrangeRangeFrom. What happens if this is the case, only 3 of the colour-coded ranges are displayed, which is fine and this is the expected behaviour. As the alternatingBandFills array is defined in this order -> red, orange,green,orange, red , the colours shown are red-orange-green. That is totally fine and expected.

However, on some of the data sets, which has the same logic as the others (i.e. lowerRedRangeFrom = lowerOrangeRangeFrom), the graph's alternatingBandFills are displayed like -> orange-green-orange.

Can someone explain me why this is the case ? The confusion comes from the fact that for a given dataset, there is no problem, and for others there is (although the proportions are the same). I know that Core-Plot will cycle through the alternatinBandFills array and display the colours, but for some reason sometimes it starts cycling at index = 1, instead of at the start at the array.

Thanks,

Petar

Answer (score 0):

That behavior is correct. If `lowerRedRangeFrom == lowerOrangeRangeFrom`, then the first red range is still there, but it has 0 height.